# Comet implementation

Tags: 7

Does anyone know how to implement [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) in Drupal?
I saw a rudimentary [PHP implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code) on Stack Overflow.
Is there any module which does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in that answer, that is blocking a whole apache thread and therefore not a good idea.

I suggest you have a look at http://drupal.org/project/nodejs. [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is an event-based webserver written in JavaScript and that is the module that integrates it with Drupal. Then, your clients keep a connection option with the node.js server and you can contact them through that server.

The project is still in development, I don't know how well it is working already.